# Nginx redirect to https issues

Tags: nginx

I been struggling for a while to find a solution for a problem that I have:
I need to redirect all http request to https excepting a specific page under a certain location.
I have the following:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  myserver;
        root         /var/www/example.org/htdocs;
        index        index.html;
        .
        .
}
```

I can't use:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
           listen         443 ssl;
           server_name    my.domain.com;
           .
           .
    }
```

I found a good solution in [here](http://www.redant.com.au/ruby-on-rails-devops/manage-ssl-redirection-in-nginx-using-maps-and-save-the-universe/)

The problem with the solution is that the redirect gets into an infinitive loop, the solution is something like, after my changes:

```
map $uri $example_org_preferred_proto {
    default "https";
    ~^/post/ "http";
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.org;
    root /var/www/example.org/htdocs;

    if ($example_org_preferred_proto = "https") {
        return 301 $example_org_preferred_proto://example.org$request_uri;
    }
}
```

I understand logic of the problem:

1. I get a request like: http://wwww.example.com/test -> redirects to https://wwww.example.com/test
2. Now I get a request like: https://wwww.example.com/test -> redirects to https://wwww.example.com/test
3. Now I get a request like: https://wwww.example.com/test -> redirects to https://wwww.example.com/test and got into a loop ....

I need a way to stop after redirect one time.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  wwww.example.com;
    root         /var/www/example.org/htdocs;
    location /test {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location / {
        return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    ## here goes other ssl staff which you can find by link:
    ## https://gist.github.com/paskal/628882bee1948ef126dd
    server_name example.org;
    root /var/www/example.org/htdocs;
    location /test {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location / {
        return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Best solution is simplest one. You need to serve only one location and redirect anything else - so do it.
If you have problem with using two server blocks, please describe it in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but like I mentioned I have:  `server {  listen       80;  listen       443 ssl;`  and I can't split my server.

Comment: @BobaFettlikesJS, why can't you?